# Selecting Images and sending data when clicking submit

Tags: php, html, session

I have 5 images that represent an interest such as hiking, swimming, snowboarding, running, climbing. I want the user to be able to click however many images they want and then once they click submit, I want to send data for each image to the next page. This data would be "hiking" "swimming" "snowboarding" "running" "climbing".

```
<input type="image" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/simpleview/image/upload/c_fill,f_auto,h_388,q_65,w_560/v1/clients/norway/hiking_moysalen_vesteralen_norway_0a6be0ac-16ad-4d48-b3d9-f58a25bcb1a2.jpg" name="hiking" >
  <input type="image" src="https://www.wellandgood.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Stocksy-Friends-Eatting-Jill-Chen.jpg" name="climbing" >
  <input type="image" src="http://coresites-cdn.factorymedia.com/mpora_new/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Snowboarding-Beginners-Tips-Advice-UK.jpg" name="snowboarding" >
  <input type="image" src="http://media.beam.usnews.com/59/52/2464cc9d45a791a798e244c87fd0/161101-comparemilk-stock.jpg" name="swimming" >
  <input type="image" src="https://cf.ltkcdn.net/online/images/std/211032-674x450-Friends-playing-video-games.jpg" name="running">
```

I only know how to send data through text inputs, is it possible to do it with image inputs?

Comment: Your question is pretty unclear. Please update your question with a more detailed explanation of what you want to do, what you've tried (you have tried something, right?), what happens when you try and where you're stuck.

Comment: depending on your request method you receive a $_GET or a $_POST array with all the elements of your form in your target

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have a image on page then you need to create check box for selecting those images.your html should be like this

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="your.php">
    <div>
        <img src="your image">
        <div class="checkbox">

            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="image value" name="images[]">
                Checkbox
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="your image">
        <div class="checkbox">

            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="image value" name="images[]">
                Checkbox
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And `your.php` file should be like this

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $images=$_POST['images'];
    foreach ($images as $image) {
        echo $image;
        echo '<br>';
        //Do something
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple Pure HTML Code

```
<form method="POST" action="" >

    <label for="imageOne">
        <img src='https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png' width='100' /></label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="image[]" id="imageOne" value="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"><br>

    <label for="imageTwo">
    <img src='https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/yc/r/GwFs3_KxNjS.png' width='100' /></label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="image[]" id="imageTwo" value="https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/yc/r/GwFs3_KxNjS.png"><br>

    <label for="imageThree">
    <img src='https://html.com/wp-content/uploads/flamingo.jpg' width='100'  /></label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="image[]" id="imageThree" value="https://html.com/wp-content/uploads/flamingo.jpg"><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Write the Below code at the end of same file

```
<?php 
  echo '<pre>';
     print_r($_POST);
  echo '</pre>';
?>
```

[Demo Result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Get8n.png)